# UIManagedDocument not opening

Tags: ios

If you create a new document and a file with same name does *not* exist in the current directory, then the app freezes. In particular the `open` function for the `UIManagedDocument` class does not call its completion handler.

On the other hand if the file *does* already exist in the current directory, then the `open` function does call the completion handler. In this case, however, there is a Core Data error printed to console.

I am testing on the iOS 12 Simulator with Xcode 10. Also tested on device.

`CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/ruben/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/####/data/Containers/Data/Application/####/tmp/mydoc.doccy/StoreContent/persistentStore options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveStoreOnCleanupKey = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Can't add the same store twice";
}`

[Example project](https://github.com/rzil/Doccy)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out after creating the document and saving to a temporary location, you need to call `close` first, before importing and opening it.